# How to achieve \dotfill in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, dotfill

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \score } { O{} m }
  {
    \mode_if_math:TF
      { \__examzh_cdotfill: \tag*{#2} }
      { \__examzh_cdotfill: #2 }
    \mode_if_math:F
      {
        \par \noindent \ignorespaces
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__examzh_cdotfill:
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em {\hss $\cdot$ \hss} \hfill
    \kern\z@
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[
    x_{k + 1} = \sqrt{2 + x_k} < \sqrt{2 + 2} = 2,
  \]
  text\score{2}
  \[
    \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x_n^2} + \frac{1}{x_n}} > \sqrt{\frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2}} = 1,\score{2}
  \]
  \begin{equation}
    \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x_n^2} + \frac{1}{x_n}} > \sqrt{\frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2}} = 1,\score{2}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{align}
    \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x_n^2} + \frac{1}{x_n}} > \sqrt{\frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2}} = 1,\score{2}
  \end{align}
  \begin{gather}
    \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x_n^2} + \frac{1}{x_n}} > \sqrt{\frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2}} = 1,\score{2}
  \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is `\dotfill` in the math mode like `\[...\]` and `align` env just like that in the text mode. But it seems that it doesn't work without any error or warning.

I wonder if there is some ways to achive it (not using `\tag` is also ok)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just leave math mode and return? (within `align` or other "predefined" environment it can be a bit problematic to make the spacing correct though.)